# Publishing multiple updates to the android market

Tags: android, google-play

If you publish multiple app updates to the Android market, and the user hasn't downloaded them yet, will Android install each update in order when they finally do update or will they only install the most recent one?

The reason I ask is that we have some code to migrate from one data format to another.  It would be nice to publish an update that does this migration, and then clean out our codebase to only use the new format going forward.  It would be safe to do this is we could be sure the Android Market would install each update in order.

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Market app will fetch and install the latest version. So if user has version 1.0 and you publish 1.1, then 1.2 and then 1.3, when user tries to update the app it will get version 1.3 directly.

By the way, if what you are upgrading is a Sqlite database, the [`SqliteDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)'s [`getVersion`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion%28%29) method could be handy.

Comment: and this is the reason you might have to install multiple database upgrades in the newer version, to upgrade from v 1.0 to 1.3.  you have to make sure you install all upgrades between the versions.

Comment: Ouch, that sucks.  Man I miss web apps.  Alright well thanks for letting me know!

Comment: It really isn't a problem.  You already had to write the code to update from 1.0 to 1.1, and 1.1 to 1.2, and 1.2 to 1.3.  The framework is intended to encourage you to write your update code so that these are distinct steps, so you just apply each of those in order to get to the current version.  For example here is the upgrade code from the system settings content provider which has gone through a large number of versions at this point: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=packages/SettingsProvider/src/com/android/providers/settings/DatabaseHelper.java

Comment: Also having all of your upgrade code included in your .apk and able to handle whatever the last version of that app that ran is a *lot* more robust than relying on knowing that the last version of the data was from some specific version.